# Monit to tigger database query

Tags: database, sql, monit

I'm new to monit service. I want to execute select query if a application server goes down using monit.
Configuration in /etc/monitrc is like:-

```
check host www.example.com with address www.example.com
       if failed port 80 protocol http 
       then exec /tmp/test.sh
```

and test.sh contains following with the permission of chmod a+x /tmp/test.sh

```
mysql -u root -p root
use database;
select * from tablename;
```

The monit service is not executing /tem/test.sh file. How can I do it using monit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and using the right parameters to the [mysql-binary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html):

This should work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u root -p root database -e "SELECT * FROM table"
```